# How can I make a client-side script respond to a click on a spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I already know how to make scripts respond to a click anywhere on a regular HTML page. But if I'm using HTML to display content on a sidebar within a spreadsheet, how could I make a script inside that HTML handle `onclick` events made anywhere in the spreadsheet? Currently, I can only make it respond to clicks within the sidebar, where the HTML resides. I'm trying to get this functionality extended to the rest of the spreadsheet.

Comment: There is no way to detect a click event inside a Google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

you cant. if you want to track the selected cell you must keep calling the backend from the sidebar using setinterval and ask it what's the selection. it's currently the only possible way to reliably track selection. add-ons do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, they haven't given Google Apps Script Access to the Spreadsheet onClick events.  The events call the functions that are given to script triggers and [here's the documentation for them.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

Comment: I've played around with triggers before, but I don't think I can get the effect I'm looking for with just triggers. Is there at least a way to get a script to automatically keep track of which cell is selected?

Comment: Well, I'm certainly not the final word but I don't know of any.  Perhaps you can be the first to find one of the undocumented tricks.

Comment: You can insert a button in a cell and assign a function to it which fires when the cell is selected. Which is similar to the onclick functionality that you're talking about.

Comment: @SuyashGandhi that's a clever idea but it won't work in my case. I'm trying to get the script to passively and automatically read the content of any cell selected by the user, without further action. Can't do that if there's a button in the way. Also, I have no control over what's in a cell. Sadly it looks like I won't be able to do exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

You can use a onEdit() trigger, which fires when someone is editing any part of the spreadsheet and then inside the function that was fired onEdit you can use the `getActiveCell()` method of class **SpreadsheetApp** to determine which cell is currently selected by the user.

**Note:** The onEdit trigger does not work if you are copy pasting data into the cells or the cells are being filled by some form of automation such as App script or Spreadsheet formulas.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good suggestion but I was hoping more for a script to be able to read cell contents passively and automatically as the user selects them without any further action.

Comment: An onEdit trigger doesn't responds to a click event.